# Pip install results in this error " cl.exe' failed with exit code 2 "

Tags: python, windows, pip

I've read all of the other questions on this error and frustratingly enough, none give a solution that works.

If I run `pip install sentencepiece` in the cmd line, it gives me the following output.

```
 src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2809): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sentencepiece_processor.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
```

I'm running python 3.10.1 and pip 22.0.3 .

*I have the following Microsoft Visual C++ programs on my windows machine,which I've just done a fresh install of as it was complaining of not having a particular C++ program.
[MS VC++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QsCD.png)

I've even added the .exe file to my PATH variables but still I get the same error.

**Am I missing a particular Microsoft program on my pc?**

Comment: I get the same annoying problem for various packages.

Comment: Yeah quite frustrating , I will try using a lower version of Python like someone mentioned below...

Comment: I have been there a few times, but compromising your python version (for one or a small subset of modules) is a suboptimal strategy (too many improvements to give up with advances in later versions). So recommend to avoid that.

Comment: I would prefer (and have in the past) to contacted the maintainers with the issue. Bringing packages forward is wat better than moving versions backwards.

Comment: I am trying to install sasl on my windows 11 machine facing same issue, I am using python 11, should i use lower version of python? By I do agree with above comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen this problem in Windows, but for Linux, I would normally reinstall Python **after** installing the dependencies (such as the MSVC thing). In that case this is especially helpful because I'm often rebuilding (compiling and other related steps) Python/Pip.

Could also just be an error specific to the module and Python version combo you're trying.

---

From a discussion in the comments:

I have the [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) version manager, so I was able to create [venvs](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/venv.html) and test this for you. With Python 3.10.2, it fails; with Python 3.8.10, it's successful. So, yes, reinstalling does seem to be worthy of your time.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same , could be the package version and python version, as running that in a colab tutorial which uses a different python version works!
Would you think it would be worth to reinstall Python in my scenario ?

Comment: I have the [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) version manager, so I was able to create [venvs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and test this for you. With Python 3.10.2, it fails; with Python 3.8.10, it's successful. So, yes, reinstalling does seem to be worthy of your time.

Comment: if you update your original answer with your latest comment , I can accept it as its helped!

Comment: Successfully installed the necessary packages using Python v3.8.10 ! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

With python3.10

On Windows: First, `install vcpkg and install sentencepiece:x64-windows-static`

copy the header and lib files from `vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/include` and lib to

`C:/Program Files/python310/build/root/include`   and lib

This should work as the setup.py install expects the library in a ..\build\root\lib  directory.

As the C:\Program Files\python310\lib  is in the /LIBPATH, the resulting ..\build\root\lib  will point to the sentencepiece.lib

If still encounting errors, then set the INCLUDE and LIB environment variables so that the cl.exe , which is called from `pip install sentencetransformers` finds them.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous that you need to do all that crap.

Answer (score 2):

People having windows+python 3.10 env, here are exact steps to install it via vcpkg.

Other instructions are covered in zweistein's answer.

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg integrate install
./vcpkg install sentencepiece:x64-windows-static
```

Comment: for windows you use: 
.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat

Answer (score 0):

If you install visual studio, Check if windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0) is installed in C++ developemtools

Comment: Feel free to add a bit more info on your next post. like providing sources and more explanation. It still is good thinking and thank you for your answer i hope you don't feel discouriged now because of my answer i just meant as feedback so dont take it personally :). Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I am not very expert, but.

I encoutered the same error when trying to `pip install gdal`.

I've tried going through many solutions mentioned around the web, but no fix.
I solved this by **downloading anaconda** and using **anaconda powershell prompt** for installing gdal package (of course I had first set up everything as needed for conda).

In your case it'd be **sentencepiece package**. So the line on conda powershell should be something like `conda install -c conda-forge sentencepiece`, and it should be installed without troubles.

After this installation, I've set my **anaconda intepreteur** into my IDE (I'm using PyCharm) for python, and set the new directory where conda hosts its packages.

The IDE updated and errors were then solved, as the conda environment hosted gdal.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following answer by minimocomunemultiplo and I managed to solve it. Thanks!
I encoutered the same error when trying to pip install gdal.

I've tried going through many solutions mentioned around the web, but no fix. I solved this by downloading anaconda and using anaconda powershell prompt for installing gdal package (of course I had first set up everything as needed for conda).

In your case it'd be sentencepiece package. So the line on conda powershell should be something like conda install -c conda-forge sentencepiece, and it should be installed without troubles.

After this installation, I've set my anaconda intepreteur into my IDE (I'm using PyCharm) for python, and set the new directory where conda hosts its packages.

The IDE updated and errors were then solved, as the conda environment hosted gdal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).